# Airbnb currency display button element uninteractable using Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm new to Python and Selenium, but especially know nothing about HTML. I'm using Selenium to scrape airbnb listings and their prices solely to increment the price filter so I can access more listings per area without hitting the 15 page cap.

I've been trying to figure out how to interact with the currency display button on an [airbnb results page](https://www.airbnb.com/s/Pike-County--PA--United-States/homes?tab_id=home_tab&refinement_paths%5B%5D=%2Fhomes&monthly_start_date=2023-08-01&monthly_length=3&price_filter_input_type=0&price_filter_num_nights=5&channel=EXPLORE&date_picker_type=flexible_dates&flexible_trip_dates%5B%5D=april&flexible_trip_dates%5B%5D=august&flexible_trip_dates%5B%5D=december&flexible_trip_dates%5B%5D=february&flexible_trip_dates%5B%5D=january&flexible_trip_dates%5B%5D=july&flexible_trip_dates%5B%5D=june&flexible_trip_dates%5B%5D=march&flexible_trip_dates%5B%5D=may&flexible_trip_dates%5B%5D=november&flexible_trip_dates%5B%5D=october&flexible_trip_dates%5B%5D=september&adults=3&source=structured_search_input_header&search_type=filter_change&query=Pike%20County%2C%20PA&zoom_level=11&place_id=ChIJXQMzOISixIkRNmmWbNFqb2w&flexible_trip_lengths%5B%5D=one_week&federated_search_session_id=3246c11b-bcbe-4098-a744-ef0846c4e420&pagination_search=true&cursor=eyJzZWN0aW9uX29mZnNldCI6MywiaXRlbXNfb2Zmc2V0IjoyNTIsInZlcnNpb24iOjF9) and choose to display USD (currently abroad for the summer and my connection is far too slow to run the program with a proxy).

I tried proxies but none free and available were usable for hours (inconsistent).
I also tried adding cookies for currency and country but kept getting 'InvalidCookieDomainException' no solutions posted on this issue worked for me.
So I decided to change the currency manually with the currency button on the bottom of the page.
For reference, this is the button element:

`<button type="button" class="_1az8yk66 l1ovpqvx dir dir-ltr"><span class="a8jt5op dir dir-ltr">Choose a currency</span><span class="_1vel3z8">$</span><span class="_144l3kj">SGD</span></button>`

I have other parts in my original code that clicks other buttons on the top of the page and scrolls to different elements successfully, but this currency button specifically does not work and I'm completely stumped.

My first attempt was to wait for the button to be clickable, here is a snippet of the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.maximize_window()

link = 'https://www.airbnb.com/s/Pike-County--PA--United-States/homes?tab_id=home_tab&refinement_paths%5B%5D=%2Fhomes&monthly_start_date=2023-07-01&monthly_length=3&price_filter_input_type=0&price_filter_num_nights=5&channel=EXPLORE&date_picker_type=flexible_dates&flexible_trip_dates%5B%5D=april&flexible_trip_dates%5B%5D=august&flexible_trip_dates%5B%5D=december&flexible_trip_dates%5B%5D=february&flexible_trip_dates%5B%5D=january&flexible_trip_dates%5B%5D=july&flexible_trip_dates%5B%5D=june&flexible_trip_dates%5B%5D=march&flexible_trip_dates%5B%5D=may&flexible_trip_dates%5B%5D=november&flexible_trip_dates%5B%5D=october&flexible_trip_dates%5B%5D=september&adults=3&source=structured_search_input_header&search_type=filter_change&query=Pike%20County%2C%20PA&zoom_level=11&place_id=ChIJXQMzOISixIkRNmmWbNFqb2w&flexible_trip_lengths%5B%5D=one_week'
driver.get(link)



currency_element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='_1az8yk66 l1ovpqvx dir dir-ltr']")))
currency_element.click()
```

This however, only resulted in a timeout, referring to the wait for element to be clickable. I assumed this meant that the element was not clickable and so I tried to access the button without waiting for it to be clickable.

```
currency_element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='_1az8yk66 l1ovpqvx dir dir-ltr']")))
currency_element.click()
```

This gave me an error of: selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
Selenium manages to locate the element but somehow cannot scroll to it or click it. I'm not sure why as it is a button?

I tried multiple solutions from similar issues posted.

1. using ActionChains to move/scroll to the element and then click.

- never actually scrolls to the bottom of the page or to where the element is located - not sure why. always returns element not interactable errors.

2. checking for iframes (none blocking)

- the only iframes on the page were nowhere near the bottom. though, I'm not actually sure how to navigate this.

3. using CSS selector to access the element

- no difference in  outcome

I also tried adding implicit waits in case any of the issues were due to connectivity and loading issues but still same errors for all. I'm not sure what exactly it is with the airbnb page that limits

Any help, ideas, or just a general push to a different direction will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Refer the below working code:** This code will launch URL --> Click on OK preference button --> Selects USD as currency

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.airbnb.co.uk/s/Pike-County--PA--United-States/homes?tab_id=home_tab&refinement_paths%5B%5D=%2Fhomes&monthly_start_date=2023-08-01&monthly_length=3&price_filter_input_type=0&price_filter_num_nights=5&channel=EXPLORE&date_picker_type=flexible_dates&flexible_trip_dates%5B%5D=april&flexible_trip_dates%5B%5D=august&flexible_trip_dates%5B%5D=december&flexible_trip_dates%5B%5D=february&flexible_trip_dates%5B%5D=january&flexible_trip_dates%5B%5D=july&flexible_trip_dates%5B%5D=june&flexible_trip_dates%5B%5D=march&flexible_trip_dates%5B%5D=may&flexible_trip_dates%5B%5D=november&flexible_trip_dates%5B%5D=october&flexible_trip_dates%5B%5D=september&adults=3&source=structured_search_input_header&search_type=filter_change&query=Pike%20County%2C%20PA&zoom_level=11&place_id=ChIJXQMzOISixIkRNmmWbNFqb2w&flexible_trip_lengths%5B%5D=one_week&federated_search_session_id=3246c11b-bcbe-4098-a744-ef0846c4e420&pagination_search=true&cursor=eyJzZWN0aW9uX29mZnNldCI6MywiaXRlbXNfb2Zmc2V0IjoyNTIsInZlcnNpb24iOjF9&_set_bev_on_new_domain=1688479971_YWJmNzlmOTM1M2Iw")
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

# Click OK button on preference
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='OK']"))).click()

# Below 3 lines of code will click on Globe icon, Currency tab and USD
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@aria-label='Choose a language and currency']"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Currency']"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='United States dollar']"))).click()

time.sleep(10)
```